# getPosition(item) from ArrayAdapter<String> gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to search for my problem, but without success.
I am filling `ArrayAdapter<String> parkingLotAdapter` from database(Parse.com). I assign this adapter to spinner. Spinner works fine, show list of items. But when I try to get position one of the item in the Adapter via `getPosition(item)` I get NullPointerException.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (ParseObject temp : parkingList) {
     list.add(temp.getString("parking_lot"));
     }
parkingLotAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
parkingLotAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
parkinglotSpinner.setAdapter(parkingLotAdapter);

int pos4 = parkingLotAdapter.getPosition("A123");
parkinglotSpinner.setSelection(pos4);
```

When I use `getPosition(item)` with other spinners which I populate from Resources and use `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`, everything works good. Can you help me with this issue.

My Logcat:

```
06-17 09:40:13.927: W/dalvikvm(26031): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41307300)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at me.aizon.app.fragments.RegisterFragment$LoadParkingSpinnerASYNC.onPostExecute(RegisterFragment.java:396)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at me.aizon.app.fragments.RegisterFragment$LoadParkingSpinnerASYNC.onPostExecute(RegisterFragment.java:1)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4746)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:917)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
06-17 09:40:13.927: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try this way : parkinglotSpinner.setSelection(list.indexOf("A123"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

You have already list object to try to get index from list instead of adapter.

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Replace this code:
int pos4 = parkingLotAdapter.getPosition("A123");
parkinglotSpinner.setSelection(pos4);

With this:
parkinglotSpinner.setSelection(list.indexOf("A123"))
```

Comment: I found my problem. I was getting data from external database. And since there was delay in data gathering I tried to place code in Async Task: getting data in doInBackground and setting selection in onPostExecute. And that's was my problem. So I just moved my gepPosition(item) or setSelection(list.indexOf("A123")) in part of code where I receive my data.