# How to set a default value to dynamic spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created three spinner that are year、month、day. Apparently my day will change base on my month.

Here is my function:

```
private void datePick() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            dataYear.add("" + (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - i));
        }

        adapterSpYear = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, dataYear);
        adapterSpYear.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spYear.setAdapter(adapterSpYear);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            dataMonth.add("" + (i < 10 ? "0" + i : i));
        }

        adapterSpMonth = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, dataMonth);
        adapterSpMonth.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spMonth.setAdapter(adapterSpMonth);

        spMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
                dataDay.clear();
                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.valueOf(spYear.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, arg2);
                int dayOfMonth = calendar1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                for (int i = 1; i <= dayOfMonth; i++) {
                    dataDay.add("" + (i < 10 ? "0" + i : i));
                }
                adapterSpDay = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, dataDay);
                adapterSpDay.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spDay.setAdapter(adapterSpDay);
                adapterSpDay.notifyDataSetChanged();


                String year = spYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String month = spMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String day = spDay.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Log.i("test", ".>>>>Year>>>>" + year);
                Log.i("test", ".>>>>Month>>>>" + month);
                Log.i("test", ".>>>>Day>>>>" + day);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Now I have a default data for example is 1960/11/24.

I try to find out the number position and use `setSelection()` to year and month and spinner will be change.

Here is what I try:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int finalResult = thisYear - 1960;
        spYear.setSelection(finalResult); //year spinner will show 1960
        spMonth.setSelection(11-1); //month spinner will show 11
        spDay.setSelection(20); //day spinner will show 1
```

I find day spinner is no working when I use `setSelection()`, I guess day spinner is dynamic base on month spinner.

But I don't know how to fix it ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to do something like this. call on adapter for position

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int finalResult = thisYear - 1960;
        int positionYear = adapterSpYear.getPosition(String.valueOf(finalResult))
        spYear.setSelection(positionYear); //year spinner will show 1960
        //same goes for month and day
```

here is existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255753/getpositionitem-from-arrayadapterstring-gives-nullpointerexception).
here is [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getPosition(T))

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but i try your code, positionYear will print -1 and my spYear is 2017 not 1960.

Comment: yes you can change accordingly to your requirement but the basic idea is to get position from adapter.

Comment: Thanks i change like this `int positionYear = adapterSpYear.getPosition(String.valueOf("1960"));
        spYear.setSelection(positionYear);`